# Copy local - .dlls not being copied

Tags: visual-studio-2010, copy-local

I have 3 projects in a Visual Studio solution. One of the projects (Driver) contains references to the .dlls produced by the other two projects. The copy local property is set to true for both. Neither of these .dlls get copied to Driver's bin/Debug directory. Isn't that what should happen?

I get runtime errors because the assemblies can't be found.

By the way, my .dlls **used to be** in the GAC but I uninstalled them.

Comment: Are you compiling all the projects at the same time?  If so, does the driver project get compiled last?  Why not have the other two projects set as references instead of copying DLLs?  I think that is the recommended way.

Comment: @Evan "One of the projects (Driver) contains references to the .dlls produced by the other two projects"

Comment: A little more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=VS.100).aspx  If I have multiple projects in the same solution, I would expect to use a project reference instead of a file reference.

Comment: @Evan I did use a project reference but it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I uninstalled from the GAC, logged out, logged back in, restarted VS 2010, cleaned the solution, then rebuilt the project...

then it worked